# How to copy memory

Tags: c, pointers

Say i have:

```
unsigned char *varA, *varB, *varC;
varA=malloc(64);
varB=malloc(32);
varC=malloc(32);
```

How can i put the **first** 32 byte of varA into varB and the **last** 32 byte of varA into varC?

Comment: Your question has remarkable little to do with pointers and you might want to rethink what it means to "split them".

Comment: I would recommend a union... just to clarify, i'm suspecting it's gonna be bits instead of bytes in the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
memcpy(varB, varA, 32);
memcpy(varC, varA + 32, 32);
```

It's this simple because the underlying data type is `unsigned char`, which is the same size as a byte. If `varA`, `varB`, and `varC` were integers, you would need to multiply the size parameter to `memcpy` (i.e. 32) by `sizeof(int)` to compute the right number of bytes to copy. If I were being pedantic, i could have multiplied 32 by `sizeof(unsigned char)` in the example above, but it is not necessary because `sizeof(unsigned char)` == 1.

Note that I don't need to multiply the 32 in `varA + 32` by anything because the compiler does that for me when adding constant offsets to pointers.

One more thing: if you want to be fast, it might be sufficient to just work on each half of `varA` separately, rather than allocate two new buffers and copy into them.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your answer, you have been very clear and exhaustive :) Then how can i work with "half of varA"? Let's say i need to do `void *function(int, half_of_varA);`, how can i pass only "half of memory"?

Comment: You would choose one of `void* p = function(1234, varA);` or `void* p = function(1234, varA + 32);` depending on which half of `varA` you need to use. And I am using 1234 as a guess as to the first parameter of `function()`, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could use loop to copy individual bytes one by one:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i != 32; ++i)
    varB[i] = varA[i];

for (int i = 0; i != 32; ++i)
    varC[i] = varA[32 + i];
```

Or `memcpy` function from the C runtime library:

```cpp
memcpy(varB, varA, 32);
memcpy(varC, varA + 32, 32);
```

Comment: Loops certainly work, but I would trust the compiler and/or `memcpy` implementer in this case. They can do tricks in the underlying assembly that a compiled loop can't touch (at least without a great optimizer), like moving multiple bytes at once.

Comment: It's just a different approaches. Copying through the loop could include some processing, like bit shuffling for example.

Comment: Yes, if processing is required, a loop is necessary.

Answer (score -3):

Ok let's do this....

```
uint64 source;
uint32 upperBytes, lowerBytes;

upperBytes = source&0xFFFFFFFF00000000;
lowerBytes = source&0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
```

Homework done.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.